# How to automatically update database value after the countdown has finished using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, database

i want to automatically update mysql database value using codeigniter when the countdown timer has finished. But i really confused how to do that. Here the example.

I have database like this 
[image]

and page like this
[image]

my countdown based on database column "timer".

The question is how can i update the value of "formlock" from 0 to 1 automatically after the countdown is finished and redirect to another page.

Here my model and controller code

```
//model
    public function getTimer(){
       $this->db->select('*');
       $this->db->from('setting');
       $query = $this->db->get();
       if($query->num_rows()>0){
        return $query->row();
       }
    }


//controller
        public function index(){
          $data['timer'] = $this->mdashboard->getTimer();
          $this->load->view('users/dashboard',$data);
        }
```

I tried this code in my views and everything i could but it doesnt worked

```
<script>
setTimeout(() => {
    windows.location.href = "<?php echo base_url()."UsersController/update"?>" //this url is controller to update data and redirect page
}, "<?php echo $timer->time;?>");
```

Any help and suggestion would be much appreciated

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Usually you could run a callback function that fires an ajax request, but in your case it seems like a bad idea. Instead of having a `boolean` column, you should have a datetime column that indicates the end of the registration. Then instead of a boolean check - you just need to compare to current time.

I'm guessing that your `time` column indicated the end of registration. It should look something like this:

```
public function index(){
  $data['timer'] = $this->mdashboard->getTimer();

  if (time() < strtotime($data['timer']['time'])) {
    $this->load->view('users/dashboard',$data);
  } else {
    // load registration closed view
  }
}
```